# .NET Core - storing Collection in MongoDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

```cs
public class Model
{
   [BsonId]
   [BsonElement("key")]
   [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.String)]
   public Guid Key {get;set;}
   [BsonElement("list_string")]
   [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Array)]
   public List<string> ListString {get;set;}
}
```

This won't work, because List != Array. The question is, how to make it work. Surely there must be a way, but for now I'm unable to solve it or find help online.

Comment: simply get rid of `[BsonRepresentation(BsonType.Array)]` all `IEnumerable` properties are stored as arrays by default. and `List` implements `IEnumerable`. so you don't need that `BsonRepresentation` attribute.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ ok, so MongoDB is smart enough to understand what I want. In what cases do I have to keep BsonRepresentation?

Comment: yes and i'd recommend you start off without any mongo attributes. if the driver is not doing what you expect by default, then look for an attribute that modifies the behavior.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ alright, but I believe I should keep at least [BsonId], or I really should let MongoDB take over?

Comment: yes if your primary key is not called `Id` then you should use [BsonId] to instruct the driver  which property is the primary key.

Comment: @ĐĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ ok so as long as it's Id it's not needed. I like when addons do things for me. But it has downsites, if something weird happens it's hard to debug.